# Cutoff and Poincare inequality

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

I want to prove the following result. Let $\psi$ be in $C^\infty_0(\mathbb{R}^n)$, $ n\geq 2$ satisfying $\psi=1$ if $|x|\leq \frac {1}{2}$ and $\psi=0$ if $|x|\geq 1$.

For $N>0$, set $\psi_N (x)=\psi (x/N)$. Then the author claim we have the following inequality
$$\Vert (\nabla \psi_N)v \Vert \leq C (n) \Vert \nabla v \Vert$$
for all $v \in C^\infty_0(\mathbb{R}^n)$.

The norm is $L^2 (\mathbb{R}^n) $.

For the case $n\geq 3$, I can prove it by using Holder and Gagliardo-Nirenberg-Sobolev inequality. But I have a problem when $n=2$.

The author mentioned that reader use Poincare inequality but the problem is the support of $v$.

How can I prove it?

The inequality comes from the paper [Form boundedness of general second-order differential operator](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/041121) (Maz'ya, Verbitsky) on page 17.

Comment: I didn't compute, but your $\psi_N$ is compactly supported and bounded, so that $\nabla\psi\in L^{\infty}\left(\mathbb{R}^{n}\right)$. Then just use Holder inequality.

Comment: @kayak The problem is on $v$. Using Poincare inequality, the constant depends on the support of $v$.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like the claim is false for $n=2$. For small $\epsilon>0$  let $v(x) = (1-\epsilon \log^+|x|)^+$ where $a^+=\max(a,0)$. Then $v =1$ on the unit ball, so the norm $\|(\nabla \psi_N )v\|$ is independent ot $\epsilon$. On the other hand, 
$$
\|\nabla v\|^2 = 2\pi \int_1^{\exp(1/\epsilon)} (\epsilon/r)^2\,r\,dr = 2\pi \epsilon  
$$
which can be arbitrarily small. This $v$ is not $C^\infty$, but it is Lipschitz with compact support, which is just as good in this context (it can be smoothed without changing either norm much).

I think the inequality still works for $n\ge 3$, but since the claim is explicitly made for $n\ge 2$, I would

1. Check the [journal form of the article](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/cpa.20122/abstract) in case the argument is changed in the final version.
2. Ask one of the authors.

Comment: I erased the comment. For the case $n\geq 3$, I can use the Gagliardo–Nirenberg–Sobolev inequality. As you mentioned, the problem is $n=2$. Thank you for your example.

Comment: I posted on the case $n\geq 3$ as an answer. I tried to use Trudinger embedding, but I failed.

Answer (score 2):

Here I give a proof in the case $n\geq 3$.

Note that $\mathrm{supp}\left(\nabla\psi_{N}\right)\subset B_{N}\left(0\right)$.
For any $v\in C_{0}^{\infty}\left(\mathbb{R}^{n}\right)$, Holder's
inequality gives 
$$
\left\Vert \left(\nabla\psi_{N}\right)v\right\Vert _{L^{2}\left(\mathbb{R}^{n}\right)}\le\left\Vert \nabla\psi_{N}\right\Vert _{L^{n}\left(\mathbb{R}^{n}\right)}\left\Vert v\right\Vert _{L^{\frac{2n}{n-2}}\left(\mathbb{R}^{n}\right)}.
$$
Now note that 
$$
\left\Vert \nabla\psi_{N}\right\Vert _{L^{n}\left(\mathbb{R}^{n}\right)}\le\frac{C}{N}\left\Vert \chi_{B_{N}\left(0\right)}\right\Vert _{L^{n}\left(\mathbb{R}^{n}\right)}=\frac{C}{N}N=C(\psi)
$$
and the Gagliardo-Nirenberg-Sobolev inequality gives
$$
\left\Vert v\right\Vert _{L^{\frac{2n}{n-2}}\left(\mathbb{R}^{n}\right)}\le C\left(n,\psi\right)\left\Vert \nabla v\right\Vert _{L^{2}\left(\mathbb{R}^{n}\right)}.
$$
Hence 
$$
\left\Vert \left(\nabla\psi_{N}\right)v\right\Vert _{L^{2}\left(\mathbb{R}^{n}\right)}\le C\left(n,\psi\right)\left\Vert \nabla v\right\Vert _{L^{2}\left(\mathbb{R}^{n}\right)},
$$
which completes the proof when $n\ge3$.

Comment: What is $C$ here?

Comment: The first constant the bound of $\psi$

Comment: Yes. As you said, the $C(n)$ depends on $\psi$.

Comment: I forgot to mention. The constant must depend on n and psi. I have to change it.